# Playing videos from data obtained in chunks

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I have recently started adding videos to ios apps using AVPlayer.But,now I have to  get video data in chunks(HLS) rather than getting all data together ,but I am not able to understand the difference between this concept of playing data obtained in chunks or playing the whole data obtained altogether as implemented below .I have tried understanding this thing and looked for examples on internet but got the same thing as already implemented by me.Kindly give your suggestions and guidance that can help me to move forward.Thanks in advance!

```
-(void)playVideo:(NSURL*)videoURL
{
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    _playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    _playerViewController.player = playVideo;
    _playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
    [playVideo play];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW3) from Apple.

When you init player, it doesn't mean that player is ready to play. You should observe player's `status` until you get `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` status.

From your code, you init player and directly start playing video. You should observe status of player by following code.

```
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];
```